# JSON validation returns different results

Tags: java, json, spring

I have created a minimal application in order to debug the following problem:

The application is creating a Java object which includes a GeoJsonPoint. When the object gets validated against an automatically created json schema, I receive different results when starting the application multiple times. For example, I am starting the application for 5 times and the result is "Json not valid!". When I start the application another time, I receive the result "Json successfully validated".

The error message when the json is not valid tells me:
/geoPosition/coordinates: instance type (array) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: [object])

The following line is randomly returning a different json schema:

```
JsonNode fstabSchema = schemaFactory.createSchema(inputObj.getClass());
```

I do not understand that this happens randomly. Has someone seen this behavior before?

To exclude dependency problems during runtime, I have created a jar with all dependencies (jar-with-dependencies)

Below are my files:

pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.reinert</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjschema</artifactId>
        <version>1.16</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.java-json-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <version>1.18.16</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

App.java:

```
package de.s2.json.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.exceptions.ProcessingException;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonPoint;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Address address = new Address();

        address.setCountry("Deutschland");

        GeoJsonPoint geoPoint = new GeoJsonPoint(12, 23);
        address.setGeoPosition(geoPoint);

        ArrayList<String> ret = null;

        try {
            ret = Toolbox.validateJson(address);
        } catch (ProcessingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(ret != null) {
            System.out.println("Json not valid!");
            for (int i = 0; i < ret.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(ret.get(i));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Json successfully validated");
        }
    }
}
```

Toolbox.java:

```
package de.s2.json.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.github.reinert.jjschema.v1.JsonSchemaV4Factory;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.exceptions.ProcessingException;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.report.ProcessingMessage;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.report.ProcessingReport;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchema;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory;


public class Toolbox {

    public static <T> ArrayList<String> validateJson(T inputObj) throws ProcessingException {

        com.github.reinert.jjschema.v1.JsonSchemaFactory schemaFactory = new JsonSchemaV4Factory();
        schemaFactory.setAutoPutDollarSchema(true);
        JsonNode fstabSchema = schemaFactory.createSchema(inputObj.getClass()); // <= here I get different results

        final JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
        final JsonSchema schema = factory.getJsonSchema(fstabSchema);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        JsonNode baseReceiptJson = objectMapper.convertValue(inputObj, JsonNode.class);
        ProcessingReport report;

        report = schema.validate(baseReceiptJson);

        ArrayList<String> validationErrorDetails = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (!report.isSuccess()) {

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            builder.append("Not all required fields are filled with data");
            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

            for (Iterator<ProcessingMessage> i = report.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                
                ProcessingMessage msg = i.next();
                builder.append(msg.asJson().findValue("instance").findValue("pointer").toString());
                builder.append(": ");
                builder.append(msg.getMessage());

                String detail = msg.asJson().findValue("instance").findValue("pointer").toString() + ": " + msg.getMessage();

                detail = detail.replace("\"", "");
                validationErrorDetails.add(detail);

                builder.append("\n");
            }
        
            return validationErrorDetails;
        }
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Address.java:

```
package de.s2.json.test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.github.reinert.jjschema.Attributes;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonPoint;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Address
{

    @JsonProperty("country")
    private String country = "";

    @JsonProperty("geoPosition")
    @Attributes(required=false, description="longitude and latitude (it is initialized with 0,0)")
    private GeoJsonPoint geoPosition = new GeoJsonPoint(0, 0);
    
}
```

Thank you very much for your support!

---

Update 1:
Answer to Hiran Chaudhuri

---

If the validation fails, then the schema looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "country": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "geoPosition": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "coordinates": {
          "type": "object"
        },
        "TYPE": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "x": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "y": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      },
      "description": "longitude and latitude (it is initialized with 0,0 which is inside the ocean)"
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"
}
```

If it is successful, then it looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "country": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "geoPosition": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "coordinates": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "number"
          }
        },
        "TYPE": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "x": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "y": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      },
      "description": "longitude and latitude (it is initialized with 0,0 which is inside the ocean)"
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"
}
```

As already in the error message indicated, one time the coordinates are an 'object' the other time an 'array'

---

Update 2

---

As this issue is blocking me to continue with my project, I have added an "ugly hack" to check in the schema if it contains a GeoJsonPoint. If it is included, it will patch it with the correct values.

```
package de.s2.json.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.github.reinert.jjschema.v1.JsonSchemaV4Factory;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.exceptions.ProcessingException;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.report.ProcessingMessage;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.report.ProcessingReport;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchema;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory;


public class Toolbox {

    public static <T> ArrayList<String> validateJson(T inputObj) throws ProcessingException {

        com.github.reinert.jjschema.v1.JsonSchemaFactory schemaFactory = new JsonSchemaV4Factory();
        schemaFactory.setAutoPutDollarSchema(true);
        JsonNode fstabSchema = schemaFactory.createSchema(inputObj.getClass());

        ArrayList<String> validationErrorDetails = new ArrayList<String>();

        // *****************************************************************************************
        // /!\ this is an ugly hack /!\
        // Randomly the function createSchema() returns an 'array' or 'object' type for coordinates
        // of the geoJsonPoint. The correct value should be array. The following code checks if a 
        // geoJsonPoint is inside the schema and overwrites it with the correct value.
        // TODO: fix this issue correctly
        // *****************************************************************************************

        try {
            String jsonCoordinate = "{\"type\": \"array\",\"items\": {\"type\": \"number\"}}";
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode jsonNodeCoordinate = mapper.readTree(jsonCoordinate);
            JsonNode coordJsonNode = fstabSchema.findValue("geoPosition").get("properties");
            ObjectNode coordObjNode = (ObjectNode) coordJsonNode;
            coordObjNode.set("coordinates", jsonNodeCoordinate);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            validationErrorDetails.add("Could not patch geoPosition");
            return validationErrorDetails;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            validationErrorDetails.add("Could not patch geoPosition");
            return validationErrorDetails;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // this means that geoPosition could not be found
            // we do nothing ...
        }
        // ******************

        final JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
        final JsonSchema schema = factory.getJsonSchema(fstabSchema);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        JsonNode baseReceiptJson = objectMapper.convertValue(inputObj, JsonNode.class);
        ProcessingReport report;

        report = schema.validate(baseReceiptJson);

        if (!report.isSuccess()) {

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            builder.append("Not all required fields are filled with data");
            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

            for (Iterator<ProcessingMessage> i = report.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                
                ProcessingMessage msg = i.next();
                builder.append(msg.asJson().findValue("instance").findValue("pointer").toString());
                builder.append(": ");
                builder.append(msg.getMessage());

                String detail = msg.asJson().findValue("instance").findValue("pointer").toString() + ": " + msg.getMessage();

                detail = detail.replace("\"", "");
                validationErrorDetails.add(detail);

                builder.append("\n");
            }
        
            return validationErrorDetails;
        }
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By serializing the JSON Schema you generated we are able now to compare whether they are the same or how much they actually differ. Take into account that the method to generate a schema requires some input parameter.

I was never a friend of generating a schema based on actual data.
Why do you not strictly define the schema you want and let your code measure whether you really meet that structure? This way you can use the schema as a contract between application components since it is documented and not generated on the fly.

This is still no answer to the question why this happens randomly. But it is maybe a better practice to follow for you and others reading along.

Comment: While this is a good tip to figure out what's happening, I think it's not really an answer and should have been a comment on the question.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have added some more information. I still do not understand why this happens randomly.

Comment: Unfortunately for this project it would be too much effort for having for every object 
 its own schema statically defined.

Comment: You are right. I'd go with a schema for a class of objects. if that is not sufficient for you, why bother at all about a schema?